# ember-data DS.RESTAdapter how to filtering data? (screen)

Tags: ember.js, filtering, ember-data

I have the table like on the screen below. I have row to filtering table. When i type in Subject column "psa" i want show only row with "psa" in Subject. The same with field selectbox where i can choose prepared options, example for status: open,close,waitin for reply.

How can i do that? What can i use?

For now i am using:

```
Table.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api/models'
  })
});
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/

Is it possible to add some additional values to RESTAdapter queries?

Other problem is when i have table with 10000 rows i don't want show all in once in table, even download all by one time. I need pagination then, show 20 per page or something like that.

What ember can offer for me?

[image: table]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1BRg.png

Comment: For filtering the data loaded from the server before it's displayed, you can use the [`App.MyModel.filter`](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/show-only-complete-todos/) on the content.

Comment: I am also looking for the correct way to setup pagination in a canonical way. Hopefully someone else will answer this.

Comment: But it doesn't have sense to filtering data on client side. Imagine somebody want list all users with name "Smi" (example Smith). In that case ember have to download 1000000 users to show 100. Filtering have to be on server side.

The same situation with pagination.

Comment: Agreed, pagination is a key feature.

Comment: Did you discover soemething?